# Regex compare whole number and ignore separators

Tags: regex

I would like to match the following pattern

> 1.XXXXXX.XXX.X

**The combination must begin with a 1 and must contain at least a second number greater than 0 somewhere. Only numbers and points allowed.**

*So the following examples would be correct*

> 1.000000.000.1
>   1.000500.000.0
>   1.020030.030.0

*And the following examples would be incorrect*

> 1.000000.000.0
>   1.0000.00.0
>   1.0000d0.020.0

What I have created so far

```
(?=^[1][\.][0-9]{6}[\.][0-9]{3}[\.][0-9]{1}$) // check pattern 1.XXXXXX.XXX.X
(?=^[1-9](?!0000000000$)[0-9][1-9]?\d+$) // check if input is greater than 10000000000
```

Unfortunately, the second statement does not work because of the points in the input. Is it possible to read the complete number and ignore the points or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^1\.(?!(?:\.?0)+$)\d{6}\.\d{3}\.\d$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BbLcYM/1)

The regex will fail the match if there are only zeros and dots after the initial `1.`.

**Details**

- `^1\.` - `1.` at the start of the string
- `(?!(?:\.?0)+$)` - a negative lookahead that will fail the match of there are  one or more sequences of an optional `.` and a zero up to the end of the string
- `\d{6}` - 6 digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `\d{3}` - 3 digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `\d` - a digit
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Holy moly. That was mindblowing fast. Thanks a lot Wiktor!